# "Forecasted" or "forecast"

Tags: verbs

With authors writing in English as a second language increasingly predominating, especially in technical fields, irregular verbs get regularized. As an editor, should I give up the Canute-like** struggle against the oncoming tide of *forecasted* and the like?

** Yes, I know ... !

Comment: I disagree. These mistakes are commonly made by native speakers of the language, as well.

Comment: Surely you mean *incoming* tide? ;^)

Comment: @Robusto: The incoming tide is *oncoming* if you are sitting in it!

Comment: @Jimi: I agree with your second statement, which is consistent with what I said, but am puzzled by your initial disagreement. What, precisely, is false in my statement?

Comment: @John: My disagreement lay with your implication of ESL authors as responsible for the onslaught of improperly conjugated irregulars. But I see now that my disagreement may have been misplaced, as it seems that your statement stems directly from your professional experience as an editor.

Answer (score 3):

As editor? Of course not!

However, in this case, according to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forecast)

> **verb**, *-cast* or *-cast·ed*

both forms are *correct*.

So, it is a matter of style and it depends on guidelines you decide to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

My advice:

- Never give up on your own stuff!  Make it as good as it can be, in grammar, style and content.
- Stop bothering about other peoples' stuff.  I call this "stop the tut"! - and try to stop myself from tutting when I see bad spelling or grammar.  English evolves :)

I found that once I let go of spelling errors in facebook posts, texts, email etc - let alone public signage or notices! - I enjoyed life more.  I might have an occasional chuckle to myself about bad grammar on a sign, and if someone asks, I'll always try to help.  But I don't correct them.

Comment: Good advice in general but @John Bentin says that he is an editor. As an editor, I don't think he can "stop bothering about other people's stuff".